# how to return column from another table with sql condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have this this biller table

```
|acq|iss|bnf|
=============
|2 |13 |553|
|9 |8  |553|
|14|22 |553|
```

and this bank table

```
|bank id| bank_name  |
====================
|2      |bank bri    |
|8      |bank mandiri|
|9      |bank bni    |
|13     |bank permata|
|14     |bank bca    |
|22     |bank cimb   |
|553    |bank mayora |
```

how to produce this table with sql ?

```
|acq      |iss          |bnf        |
=====================================
|bank bri |bank permata |bank mayora|
|bank bni |bank mandiri |bank mayora|
|bank bca |bank cimb    |bank mayora|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - you need to join with multiple instances of bank table

```
select b1.bank_name as acq, b2.bank_name as iss,b3.bank_name as bnf
from biller b inner join bank b1 on acq=b1.bank_id
inner join bank b2 on iss=b2.bank_id
inner join bank b3 on bnf=b3.bank_id
```